# Why to define the number of steps for evaluate() of class estimator?

Tags: tensorflow

why is useful to define the number of steps when calling the evaluate() function of class estimator?

```
nn = tf.contrib.learn.Estimator(model_fn=model_fn, params=model_params, model_dir= direc)

# Fit
nn.fit(x=training_set.data, y=training_set.target, steps=500)

# Score accuracy
ev = nn.evaluate(x=test_set.data, y=test_set.target, steps=1)
```

Should it not be the case that for evaluate() the number of steps is always 1?

Answer (score 0):

The parameter steps is useful for cases when your generator of features and targets does not stop after one epic.  There are several different combinations of x=, y=, input_fn=, feed_fn=, and steps= that are allowed (and many that are disallowed).  Since Estimator is still in `tf.contrib.learn`, it is still under active development by the Google team.  It sounds like Estimator will move to the `tf.core` in version r1.1 sometime in April.  Until then, documentation is sparce, and likely to change.